# How do I convert a .FITS into a numpy array (or a file that can be used in Python)?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, computational-physics, software, photometry

I'm trying to train an AI algorithm to determine photometric redshifts of galaxies, and to do so I have a .FITS file which contains the training data. I need to convert this .FITS file into a format which can be manipulated easily in Python, specifically a numpy array. I have already tried using astropy and followed the below youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goH9yXu4jWw

however, when I attempt to convert the file and then inspect the data type, it is still a .FITS file and not a numpy array. If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated!

```
import astropy.io
from astropy.io import fits


truth_north = fits.open('dr9_pz_truth_north.fits')

data = truth_north[1].data
```

Comment: Consider the [astropy package](https://www.astropy.org/).

Comment: I might be able to help you if you include your code in your question (specifically the lines where you convert from FITS to numpy array).

Comment: According to the astropy documentation (https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html) your *data* should indeed be a numpy array. What do you get if you print *type(data)* ? What do you get if you print *data[:20]* ?

Comment: @gandalf61 when I print type(data) it gives astropy.io.fits.fitsrec.FITS_rec  and when I print data[:20] it prints the FITS_rec[] array

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe it might be better suited to Stack Overflow rather than Phys.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... when I print type(data) it gives astropy.io.fits.fitsrec.FITS_rec

*FITS_rec* is a sub-class of *numpy.recarray* -see https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/tables.html#fits-rec, which says

> It inherits all of the standard methods from numpy.ndarray.

So in effect *data* is a numpy array - any method that works on numpy arrays should work on $data$, and the *FITS_rec* class may provide some additional methods as well.

Note that the original file has not been changed by this in any way - you program has simply opened the file (probably read-only by default) and created an internal representation of the data that it contains.